# Enforcing use of properties to interact with class field even though the field is exposed

Tags: c#, properties, field

I have a base class that is used by all drawable elements in my project. It owns a Rectangle, which needs to exposed to all subclasses because it needs to be passed in as a parameter in various situations. Super straight-forward:

```
public abstract class DrawableSurface
{       
protected Rectangle m_Rect;

public Vector2 Position
    {
    get { return m_Rect.Location; }
    set { m_Rect.Location = value; }   
    }     

etc. ...
```

The area, position etc. of that Rectangle are usually synonymous with the class' area and position, but I want to enforce the convention that all clients (who subclass the base) have to go through the class' properties to interact with the Rectangle.
In other words, I have a protected class that clients have access to so that they can pass it to functions, but I never want them to do any direct m_Rect.Whatever accesses.

Is there a good way of enforcing this convention (beyond documentation?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either the subclasses have access to the field or they don't - it's as simple as that. You can't give them access to the field "only for the sake of passing the value directly as an argument to another method".

Personally I'd make it a private *field*, but expose a protected property:

```
// Make it readonly if possible...
private Rectangle m_rect;

// Only expose a setter if you need it.
protected Rectangle { get { return m_rect; } }
```

If you could say more about the circumstances in which the rectangle is needed as a method argument, we may be able to help further... but you need to accept the fundamental choice between the subclasses having at least read access to the `Rectangle` reference or not - there's no middle ground.

Aside from anything else, if you *could* give them access to the `Rectangle` just to pass it to another method, what would be to stop them from writing code like this:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    SneakyMethodWithRectangle(RectangleJustForPassing);
}

private void SneakyMethodWithRectangle(Rectangle rectangle)
{
    // Ha ha! I have access to the rectangle! 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't work for me because if somebody who subclasses the base can get the Rect, he can use dot notation to access any of its fields. But I want them to use special properties I've written to interact with the fields (both when getting and setting), because those properties do some extra work on top of simply returning or setting the field.

Comment: There might not be a good solution here - if I expose the Rect, people can read/write from/to its internals. Obviously. I want clients to have a reference to the Rect, but prevent them from interacting with any of the internals *directly*. And it's mostly about documentation - telling other programmers "you can do this, but you shouldn't! Use the properties instead."

Comment: Can you use some sort of immutable rectangle instead?

Comment: @Drakestar: What could the clients do to the rectangle that you want to prevent? That sounds like the thing you should be attacking.

Comment: I think I'll just have to create a wrapper class for the Rect that exposes all the variables I want people to use via properties. Clients still have direct access to the Rect, but I'm not worried about "malicious" behavior, just documentation. For that full access, they'll  go through a well-named Property name instead (public Rectangle GetRectForDraw() or something similar), which helps preventing accidental abuse.

Comment: @Jon: If the OP can't make it `readonly`, couldn't he just use `protected Rectangle MyRect { get; private set; }` (insert obligatory complaining that auto-implemented properties don't support a `readonly` flag) ? Also, your property getter is missing a name.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the visibility of `m_Rect` to `private`.